# Can I tell if an R script is running under littler?

Tags: r

Python has this handy construct:

```
def do_stuff():
  whatever
if __name__ == "__main__":
  do_stuff(()
```

so that if the file is run from the command line with `python foo.py` or `./foo.py` and the appropriate shebang line, then the `__name__` variable is set to `__main__` and the file runs as a script. However you can also do `from foo import do_stuff` from an interactive shell or other python code and run `do_stuff` from there. The same script file is then acting as a module instead of as a script.

Can I do something similar in `littler` scripts? Something like `foo.R` being:

```
#!/bin/env r
do_stuff = function(){
  whatever
}
if(?run as r command_line?){
 do_stuff()
}
```

Then I can `source("foo.R")` and that would define `do_stuff` (in my default global environment, but we'll gloss over that for a bit).

One possible key is the presence of `_` in the environment when running under `littler` (set to the script name) but something a little stronger might be nice.

Comment: From http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler/README: *'littler provides convenience by assigning the script arguments to an "argv" vector and placing that into the global environemt, a convention followed by other popular scripting languages.'*. Perhaps you could check for the existence of `argv` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/r --vanilla

doStuff <- function(print_me) {
  print(print_me)
}

if (!interactive()) {
  if (exists("argv")) {
    if (!is.null(argv) && length(argv)>0) {
      doStuff(argv[1])
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks as good as we'll get. The innermost `if` is really a check that `argv` is correct for `doStuff` rather than part of the test that the script is running under `littler`. Also this breaks if you use `argv` as a global in your functions and so you need to set it in your calling code, but that's probably a bad idea. Its harder to break this pattern in Python since `__file__` is a module-level variable set by the loader.